# MySQL on update cascade is not updating the parent FK

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

My main goal is to get the last update time for all of my data.

Details:
I have a table - Groups

```
groupId
groupName
timeUpdated (timestamp - on update)
```

And another table - users

```
userId
timeUpdated (timestamp - on update)
groupId (FK to Groups)
ADD CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`groupId`) REFERENCES `groups` (`groupId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```

When I update the users table I want my relative groups row to get updated with the new timestamp.

I thought it should work, unfortunately it's not functioning

any ideas/ what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Omri

Comment: It doesn't work that way.  If you change the PK that the FK is referencing, the FK value will update with the `CASCADE` option... not the other way around.

Comment: OK, thanks, Is there a smart way to do that?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you are changing the PK of a record, you have a design problem.  Try updating your question about what you are trying to do rather than the way you are trying to do it, and someone should be able to help you more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to to use your `timeUpdated` column in your `Groups` table in two different ways.  This is probably not really what you want to do.

Instead, let the `Groups` table keep the update timestamp for changes to the `Groups` table, and the `Users` table recording the latest updates to the `Users` table.

When you are looking for the last time any membership information changed in the Groups table, you can query like so:

```
select 
    g.groupid,
    g.groupname,
    g.timeupdated as grouplastchanged,
    max(u.timeupdated) as lastuserchanged 
from 
    groups as g
inner join
    users as u
    on u.groupId = g.groupId
group by
    g.groupid,
    g.groupname,
    g.timeupdated;
```

Or, if you want to get really fancy, you can do something like this:

```
select 
    g.groupid,
    g.groupname,
    greatest(g.timeupdated, max(u.timeupdated)) as lastmodified
from 
    groups as g
inner join
    users as u
    on u.groupId = g.groupId
group by
    g.groupid,
    g.groupname;
```

If you're expecting a bunch of users and groups, I recommend indexing the `groupid` column in the `Users` table.